# Get Qr scanner information

Tags: node.js, embedded, qr-code, scanning

I have 2 er80 QR scanners ([datasheet](http://www.accesscontro.com/en/Products/opticialidentification/QRreader/2020-03-18/189.html)) (connected to my pc via usb), and I have my application written in node js.
Assuming that I have 2 doors and each scanner is mounted to a door (one for entering and one for exiting), how could I know which scanner scanned a QR code so I could know which door to open

1- I tried to use serial communication with the er80 but couldn't, (er80 is acting like a virtual keyboard)
2- tried to use scanner-to-buffer (which for linux uses scanimage), and my device did not find any device

Comment: As a "keyboard wedge" (HCI device) , you'd have to get into the low-level and identify the "keyboard" by its USB serial number - normally you would just get key events with no indication of the source.  Not sure if that is easy in node.js.  Using the RS-232/485 interface they will be on independent ports.  It would be easier I suspect to use TCP/IP and access the devices via your network.  The "keyboard interface" is best suited to an individual device, and is rather inflexible in any event.

Comment: Simple answer is that if you want to distinguish between two devices connected to one system, do not use an HCI/Keyboard interface.  In that sense it is a system/hardware design issue not a software development issue, so off-topic on SO.

Comment: Ok, by the power of Google it seems that it may be possible to determine which of more than one "keyboard" an input came from.  Since you mentioned Linux specifically: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72483/how-to-distinguish-input-from-different-keyboards.  It would still be far less trouble to use TCP/IP or independent serial ports.

Comment: ... however in the event interface described, you get key scan codes rather than a character sequence, so you will need to process the input further to generate the QR character sequence.  These will presumably be USB HID scan codes, so https://gist.github.com/MightyPork/6da26e382a7ad91b5496ee55fdc73db2 and https://deskthority.net/wiki/Scancode#USB_HID_Usage_Codes may be useful.  You will have to keep track of "shift state" if the character sequence may use upper and lowercase or other "shift" characters. If it is just alphanumeric and case insensitive, it is easy.

Comment: holy, first of all, thank you for responding multiple times, second (updates) => we found a program to convert the scanner from communicating as a virtual keyboard to com port numbers, so I used a library called "serialPort" in node and added an event listener to the connection, and now I can get the QR code as a buffer and then I turned it back to a string

Comment: currently, I am trying to do as you said @Clifford the TCP/IP  approach
but I am confused, how  can I "access the devices via the network", when I don't know its IP or the port

Comment: Yes, the documentation for the device is entirely inadequate on that score (and in fact in every other way).  It possibly  present as a DHCP client and has a hostname related to some unique ID such as it's serial number.  Who knows!?   Get a router with DHCP server attach the devices and interrogate the router's admin console to see how the device presents itself would be my starting point.  Choose better documented hardware in future would be my suggestion.

Comment: If you have the option for virtual com port over USB, that too will be fine (though also undocumented AFAIK).  The advantage of TCP/IP is that the door entry application can reside on any computer on the network, allowing it to be remote and for backup/redundant systems to be implemented, whereas with USB it must reside in the PC the device is attached to, and cable length is limited.